# How to use for loop in Mathematica?

Tags: procedural-programming, iteration

in most of my job I have to repeat something for different part of data, for example making plot, usually the only thing need to change is index. Below is the example of the code which I have to change it manually, I want to know how to use for loop, or another method, to make the change automatically.

```
Rse1xytyp1 = Select[section1, #[[5]] == 1 &];
se1xytyp1 = SortBy[Rse1xytyp1[[All, {3, 4}]], Last];
Length[se1xytyp1]
se1Arctyp1 = SortBy[Rse1xytyp1[[All, {2, 5}]], Last];
Length[se1Arctyp1]
s1xyplot1 = 


ListPlot[se1xytyp1, PlotStyle -> RGBColor[1.0000, 0, 0.3647],
AxesLabel -> {"X", "Y"},
PlotLabels -> Placed[{"Type 1, Section 1"}, Above]];

s1arcplot1 =
ListPlot[se1Arctyp1, PlotStyle -> RGBColor[1.0000, 0, 0.3647],
 AxesLabel -> {ArcLength, "Type"},
PlotLabels -> Placed[{"Type 1, Section 1"}, Above]];
```

In This code, in first line `Rse1xytyp1 = Select[section1, #[[5]] == 1 &];` I need to change the `#[[5]] == 1 &` from 1 to 15 then plot everything. Also I like to change the plot's names too. How can I do it?

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134609/why-should-i-avoid-the-for-loop-in-mathematica

Comment: Do[ ...  `#[[5]] == i & `..., {i,1,15}]

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest not using a for loop neither naming each plot with a different name. First, create a function that does everything you need, which takes this variable quantity as an argument and returns a list with the two plots:

```
selectAndPlot[sect_,key_]:= 
Module[{Rse1xytyp1,se1xytyp1,selArctyp1,s1xyplot1,s1arcplot1},
Rse1xytyp1 = Select[sect, #[[5]] == key &];
(* here follows all the code you have included in the question *)
{s1xyplot1,s1arcplot1}
] (* closes Module[] *)
```

Then, Map[ ] this function in the required range and keep the result in a list:

```
plotList=selectAndPlot[#,section1]&/@Range[1,15]; 
(* keep this semicolon to avoid useless output *)
```

Finally, generate any array of graphics you need. Note that each plot has a single id, for instance  plotList[[3,2]] is s1arcplot1 for key==3. Having all plots in a list helps:

```
GraphicsGrid[plotList[[1;;3]] ]  
(* draws a stacked pair of the two plots for keys 1, 2, and 3 *)
```

I could not test the program, since I don't have the data, hence this code snippet may have typos or mistakes; I hope the general idea is clear.